# Upload multiple files to azure blob at a time

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

i am trying to upload files to azure blob, i have referred [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh875756.aspx) code for the same.
and i am able to successfully upload files too, my problem is..

using this code i have to upload files one by one and i am getting more than one files at a time so each time i need to iterate over the list and pass files one by one

what i want to do is to upload all files to azure blob in one go.

i tried searching on internet but unable to find any way :(

please help

Comment: Why can't you call `MyUploadBlob` method in parallel? I haven't worked in Java for a long time so I don't know how parallel processing is supported there.

Comment: that will introduce threading complexity to very simple code of file upload, i was wondering if any API support is there for the same.
i also tried searching API docs(like we have in Java) for Azure api but couldn't found:(, is there any other way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Azure API does not have support for multi-file upload. This is something you would need to do in your application.

Comment: ok, Thanks Gaurav, by the way i have learned a lot from your blogs also.. thanks for that too:)

Answer (score 0):

Not relevant to Java, but you may check out the AzCopy tool which might be useful to you. It supports uploading blobs in parallel.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token.aspx