# How to run api for mulitple requests in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-blob-storage

I have one scenario where I am trying to upload file from UI and then in .net core i have created an endpoint which push the file in azure blob storage and after that I have an azure function written which triggers automatically and makes a call to another API which further process that file and have some sort of SQL queries written and after processing a file it generates some data and then I push that generated file again to blob to some different container. But I am facing one issue if I upload single file it works fine for me but when i upload one file and then i upload another file then my second file discards my first processing of data and in my second container I get only one exported file which is for the second uploaded file. So I want that as many user can upload the file but all process should run it should not discard any running process.
If you guys suggest me any approach that will be helpful for me. I will share my code if needed

Uploading file Endpoint

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("uploadFileToBlob")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileToBlobStorage(IFormFile file)
    {
            var userId = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
            _manageClaim.UploadExcelToBlob(file, accessToken, userId);
            return Ok(new { Message = "Your file is uploaded and processing..."});
    }
```

Repository of this Endpoint

```
 public void UploadExcelToBlob(IFormFile file, string accessToken, string userId)
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("infolder");

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "test.xlsx"
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);

            container.Metadata.Clear();
            container.Metadata.Add("bearerToken", accessToken);
            container.SetMetadata();

            Stream myBlob = file.OpenReadStream();
            blockBlobReference.UploadFromStream(myBlob);

            var currentUser = _automationUsers.GetUserById(int.Parse(userId));

            BatchClaimStatus batchClaim = new BatchClaimStatus()
            {
                UserId = int.Parse(userId),
                UserName = currentUser.FirstName + ' ' + currentUser.LastName,
                InputFileName = file.FileName,
                IsExported = false,
                ErrorMessage = null,
                OutputFileName = null,
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                UploadedDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            _blobRepository.AddImportedFileToDb(batchClaim);
        }
```

API Endpoint This endpoint get hit automatically when i upload any file from my UI

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getBatchClaimData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportToCsv(List<CsvPropModel> model)
{
await _manageClaim.GetClaimData(model);
return Ok();
}
```

This is the repository of Above endpoint

```
 public async Task<bool> GetClaimData(List<CsvPropModel> csvProps)
        {

            var dataRange = new List<ClaimsResponse>();
            ClaimsResponse claims = new ClaimsResponse();

            foreach (var item in csvProps)
            {
                InvoiceResult invoice = _manage.GetInvoiceDetailsByInvoiceId(item.InvoiceId, item.NickName);
                EligiblePaymentStatusParameters eligibleParams = Converter.ConvertInvoiceToEligibleParams(invoice);

                claims = await GetClaimDetails(eligibleParams, invoice);

                claims.InvKey = invoice.InvKey;
                claims.NickName = invoice.NickName;
                claims.InvoiceNumber = invoice.InvNbrDisplay;

                dataRange.Add(claims);
            }

            var csvRecord = ClaimDataHelper.ConvertToCsvReCord(dataRange);
            var fileName = @$"{ DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() }_ExportedBatchClaim_{ DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() }.csv";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        csv.WriteRecords(csvRecord);
                        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);

                        // Create the blob client.
                        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
                        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("outfolder");

                        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "test.xlsx"
                        CloudBlockBlob blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        memoryStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        await blockBlobReference.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
                        ms.Flush();

                        
                        var importedData = _blobRepository.GetLastImportedData();
                        
                        BatchClaimStatus batchClaim = new BatchClaimStatus()
                        {
                            ErrorMessage = null,
                            InputFileName = importedData.InputFileName,
                            IsExported = true,
                            OutputFileName = fileName,
                            UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                            UploadedDate = importedData.UploadedDate,
                            UserId = importedData.UserId,
                            UserName = importedData.UserName
                        };

                        _blobRepository.UpdateExportedFileToDb(batchClaim, importedData.Id);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Based on your process, you should submit sample code into this post because there are invisible things in your code. I prefer to see how you create a process and this line causes your process has been discarded.

Comment: @JohnathanLe I have Edited my question and added the code so The code with endpoint "getBatchClaimData" is called automatically whenever i hit endpoint "uploadFileToBlob" but when i upload twice in row it discards first one and process the second one can you help me here it would be great help

Comment: I take a look on these code but don't find any problem, and I really don't understand your business here. Did you log to ensure the first process has been called in the second api? This is a sign to help us prevent a problem from UI (javascript maybe)

Comment: @JohnathanLe The main business logic here is that if i upload some big file from UI which have lets say more than 10000 records and i want to process that all record and i dont want user to wait for output so after uploading the file i process it on background. so when my file is processed and ready for export and then i show the exported file in UI after my whole process is done. 

So what i did is when i upload the file my azure function get trigger automatically and then my azure function call this "getbatchclaim" endpoint to export the file but it cant process multiple files

Comment: Ok i got your point. So the problem might be occurred in your Azure Function. Remembered that you use Azure Function to be triggered by Azure Blob, it has a limitation about concurrency and memory [here](https://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Improving-Azure-Functions-Blob-Trigger-Performance-and-Reliability-Part-1-Memory-Usage). Normally Azure Function isn't reliability to be triggered by Blob and it is so heavy mechanism. I recommend you to use EventGrid to be triggered your Azure Function. At the end of `UploadExcelToBlob` method, just notify one completed message to Event Grid.

Comment: It Seems same issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515762/upload-multiple-files-to-azure-blob-at-a-time/19990585](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515762/upload-multiple-files-to-azure-blob-at-a-time/19990585)

Comment: Also, on a side note, I see some of your code has sync calls e.g. _blobRepository.UpdateExportedFileToDb(batchClaim, importedData.Id);. Though not directly related to this problem, but an observation to improve. For IO bound operations, we should try to use async everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem as such in your above code which can cause this though you should always try to make any IO bound operation e.g. `_blobRepository.UpdateExportedFileToDb(batchClaim, importedData.Id)` or `_manageClaim.UploadExcelToBlob(file, accessToken, userId)` *async* to improve concurrency.

The actual issue seems to be around Azure Function blob trigger. Sometimes you might face issues in blob trigger (specially for Function consumption plan) like going idle, missing trigger or delay in queue processing.

For high throughput scenario, speed and reliability, it is recommended to use [EventGrid trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid) for Function if you are using storage V2. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview) for more details and this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?tabs=dotnet).